# Bounding Rect for Triangle or Pie Slice

Tags: python, qt, rectangles, bounding, pie-chart

I'm having an issue where I have these "Pie Slices" and each one needs to be selectable BUT due to the nature of Qt it seems each on can only have a bounding rectangle. I'd need some kind of triangle. Using a rectangle would mean that each slice's rectangle would overlap with the other slices rectangles or each rectangle would have to be undersized to fit in the slice which would leave a lot of other empty space in the slice.

Any ideas?

[image: Pie Slice Image]
Here's the class I created to generate the Slices if it helps:

```
class Link_Point(QGraphicsItem):
    """ Connection points for object link """
    RECT                = Component_Point.RECT.adjusted(BORDER_WIDTH/2, BORDER_WIDTH/2, -BORDER_WIDTH/2, -BORDER_WIDTH/2)


    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(Link_Point, self).__init__(parent)

        # Vars
        self.type       = type
        self.start_angle= 0
        self.span       = 0

        # Settings
        self.setFlags(  QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable  |
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | # ********* remove this line
                        QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable   )


    def Set_Span(self, start_angle, span):
        self.start_angle= start_angle
        self.span       = span
        self.update()


    def boundingRect(self):
        # *** set bounding rect propperly
        return Component_Point.RECT


    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # Draw Pie Slice
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setStyle(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        brush   = QBrush(LINKCOLOR_DIC[self.type])
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawPie(Link_Point.RECT, self.start_angle, self.span)
```